# 3 problems with my radio buttons

Tags: jquery

I have a jsfiddle application [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6TcwS/1/) and I have a problem when it comes to displaying the radio buttons correctly.

If you open up the application you will see a set of radio buttons on top. Please select one of the radio buttons and then after that click on the "Add Radio Buttons" Button to add the radio buttons below in a table row. Now the problem is:

1. first of all the word "Multiple" does not appear in the table row for the second radio button. This should appear.
2. second of all it does not check the radio button I have selected on top. E.g If I have selected "Single" on top, when I add a new row, it should check the radio button for "Single" in the new row.
3. finally, I can select a radio button in the table row but if I do this then the selection of one of the radio buttons on top becomes unchecked. This shouldn't happen.

If I check a radio button in one of the table rows, it should not have any affect on the radio bottoms at the top.

How can these problems be fixed?

Comment: You have to get the value of the radio (single/multiple) in your function and then create logic to add the proper element to the DOM. `if ($('.replyBtn').val() == 'single') {/*do single code*/} else {/*do multiple code*/}`

Comment: Also, all form elements with the same name share values. So don't name the new inputs `reply`. Name then something unique like `reply_1` so they can have their own unique value. BTW I voted to close because it doesn't appear as though you have attempted to solve your issues on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are creating new input radio buttons but not giving them unique names. And also to retain the checked status you have to first find the checked element from the top radio buttons and set it for the newly created radio buttons.

I have fixed all the 3 issues which have mentioned take a look in the working demo.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6TcwS/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

1) The text nodes need to be contained in something. It worked correctly when I added a `<p>` tag around the HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/6TcwS/2/

2) That's because you're parsing new HTML to generate the buttons when you add them below. You'll have to clone the real DOM element from the page if you want to preserve the button state: http://jsfiddle.net/6TcwS/6/

3) You'll have to change the names of the new buttons to avoid that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

here is your modified function: ans of 1 and 2

```
function insertQuestion(form) {
    var $tbody = $("<tbody></tbody>");
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer'></tr>");
    var $replies = $("<td class='noofreplies'></td>");
    var $this = $(this);
    var $btnReply = "<input type='radio' name='reply1' value='single' class='replyBtn' checked=" + $(':radio[value="single"]').is(':checked') + " /> Single<br /><input type='radio' name='reply2' value='multiple' class='replyBtn' checked=" + (':radio[value="multiple"]').is(':checked') + " /> Multiple";
    $replies.append($btnReply);
    $tbody.append($tr);
    $tr.append($replies);
    $('#qandatbl').append($tbody);
}
```

for ans 3: don't use same name for both radios